# Сравнить элементы вектора разных индексов между собой

Tags: python, numpy

Есть одномерный numpy массив `arr`.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([56.58, 56.63, 56.39, 56.57, 56.74, 56.88, 56.71, 56.61, 56.64, 56.7,
                57.23, 57.28, 57.46, 57.41, 57.35, 57.67, 57.52, 57.32, 57.29, 57.54])
```

Задача сравнить разные элементы с разными индексами между собой сохранив структуру вектора.

```py
arr[-5] < arr[-4] and arr[-4] < arr[-3] and arr[-3] > arr[-2] and arr[-2] > arr[-1]
```

В результате ожидаю увидеть:

```py
# array([nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 0.  0.])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с циклом:

```py
res = np.full_like(arr, np.nan)

for i in range(5, len(arr)):
    res[i] = arr[i - 5] < arr[i - 4] and arr[i - 4] < arr[i - 3] and arr[i - 3] > arr[i - 2] and arr[i - 2] > arr[i]

print(res)
```

Результат:

```py
# array([nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 0.  0.])
```